# jQuery Autocomplete override trigger key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a input textbox with autocomplete that I implemented using jQuery-ui autocomplete. The autocomplete suggestions are populated based on the caret position, so it is a function of the context in which the caret is currently positioned.

Because the suggestions change based on the caret position, I want to be able to recompute the suggestions every time the caret's position changes. Is there a way to override the trigger key, so that the suggestions are also shown for left and right arrows?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this by doing something like

```
textBox.keydown(function(event){
   if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT){
       var currentText = $(textBox).data('ui-autocomplete').term;
       textBox.autocomplete('search', currentText); //this forces invalidation of the menu (this is what I was looking for)
   }
})
```

I force this invalidation of the menu, so that the context aware suggestions are recomputed.